# Install of 'R' unstable on Ubuntu

Tags: r, dependencies, installation, reinstall

I tried to install R on Ubuntu (14.04) with this command:

sudo apt-get install r-base

The network connection went down during the download / install so I had to end the download (ctrl-c). I retried the same command to restart and it is a mess. There are indications of all kinds of dependency problems. I researched and tried 'sudo apt-get remove r-base' (along with autoremove) and that does not allow me to try to reinstall. In fact, I have tried all kinds of ways to remove but nothing. How can I rectify this? Thank you!

Comment: You may want to post this on [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/)

Comment: `sudo apt-get install r-base` will get you either the release version of R (if you point to the CRAN repos) or the 'old-release' version that was current when 14.04 was made.  But your question is mistitled:  "how to recover aborted installation" is more like it -- this has nothing to do with R right now.